# COMO RETORNAR VOID EN ASM

Tags: c, asm

Hola soy nueva en esto del asm, tengo un ejercicio que consiste en tener un arreglo de una longitud determinada por ejemplo [2,3,4] luego dividir cada termino con el siguiente y el ultimo termino con el primero, en este caso [2/3,3/4,4/2], si esta division es mayor a 1 se reemplaza la posición por 1, sino por 0 [0,0,1]. Ya hice el codigo funcional en C pero alguna sugerencia para asm, se me hace muy difícil nose como manejar arreglos ahi.

```
extern void arreglo(float *lista, int longitud);
void arreglo (float *lista, int longitud){
    float divisiones_antes_ultima,division_ultima;
    for(int i=0; i<=longitud;i++){
        if(i != longitud-1){
            divisiones_antes_ultima= lista[i]/lista[i+1];
            if(divisiones_antes_ultima>1){
                lista[i]=1;
            }
            else{
                lista[i]=0;
            }
        }
        if (i==longitud-1){
            division_ultima= lista[i]/lista[0];
            if(division_ultima>1){
                lista[i]=1;
            }
            else{
                lista[i]=0;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Este el codigo que llegue mas o menos con asm pero nose como continuar,

```
global arreglo
section .text

xor r10, r10
xor rax, rax
xorpd xmm0, xmm0
xorpd xmm1, xmm1

mov rax, rdi  ; lista1
mov r9, rdi   ; copia de la lista1
mov r10, rsi  ; longitud
mov r11,0     ; contador
dec r10


movss xmm0, [rax]
add r9, 4
movss xmm1, [r9]
divss xmm0, xmm1
add rax,4
add r11
cmp r11, r10
je iguales

iguales:
```